# JQuery toggle not working in android

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using JQuery slidetoggle to show/hide divs onclick. It works perfectly in windows browsers but not in android chrome.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".content_div").hide();
          $('.show').click(function(){
            $('.content_div').slideToggle();
          });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="show">Show/Hide</div>

    <div class="content_div">content</div>
```

It doesn't work in Android Chrome. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue on my android.

Trying to use JQuery toggle would display my element, but not hide it again.

Finally went back to using straight Javascript to handle the toggle.

I found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073702/how-to-toggle-element-visibility-without-jquery) that implemented the basic feature (hide/show) but not much else.