# Expand/Collapse with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest me how to perform expand and collapse operation with one click. I mean if I click on *"pencil"* it will expand like shown in **figure 2** , and when I click on *"natraj Pencil"* it will also expand as shown in **figure 3**.

Now if I again click on *"natraj Pencil"* it will close as show in **figure 2** , and when I click on *"pencil"*, it will close  as shown in  **figure 1**. And all this operation needs to be performed with JavaScript, not jQuery.

---

**Figure 1**

```
Pencil
```

---

**Figure 2**

```
Pencil  
    Natraj Pencil  
    Afsara Pencil  
    Cello Pencil
```

---

**Figure 3**

```
Pencil
    Natraj Pencil
         Natraj sented Pencil
         Natraj strechable Pencil
    Afsara Pencil
    Cello Pencil
```

Comment: you need to share the relevant html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073702/how-to-toggle-element-visibility-without-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function toggle(obj) {

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);

    el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );

}
```

Comment: Quoting the OP: `...And all this operation needs to be performed with JavaScript, not Jquery.`

Comment: Mr Prash  i need  the code with Javascript, not Jquery, i mentioned it above

Answer (score 0):

May you want to use this javascript: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this type of example...

HTML:

```
<ul id="lists">
    <li>
        <h3 id="accordion" class="mainText" onclick="brand();">Pencil</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="topText" class="hideCode">
            <h4 onclick="items();">Natraj Pencil</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="subItems1" class="hideCode">
            <h5>Natraj sented Pencil</h5>
        </div>
        <div id="subItems2" class="hideCode">
            <h5>Natraj strechable Pencil</h5>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="middleText" class="hideCode">
            <h4>Afsara Pencil</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="BottomText" class="hideCode">
            <h4>Cello Pencil</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .showCode {
        display: block;
    }

    .hideCode {
        display: none;
    }

    h4 {
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    h5 {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
```

And finally Working Example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H93Qs/)